# jQuery UI sortable and draggable prevent moving draggable item to sortable last child

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the JQueryUI to implement drag and sort.

The problem is how to make the sortable reject draggable item if the draggable item placed after the sortable last child?

```
<ul id="draggable">
    <li>Drag Item 1</li>
    <li>Drag Item 2</li>
    <li>Drag Item 3</li>
    <li>Drag item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li> 
    <li>Last item</li> //if I placed drag item after this, the sortable list reject the drag item
</ul>
```

1. I drag the Drag Item 2 to sortable
2. If the the Drag Item 2 placed before the last child of sortable -> normal scenario happened
3. If the the Drag Item 2 placed after the last child of sortable -> the sortable list reject the Drag Item 2

Any Suggestion??
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my problem.
you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/KE2JM/3/

Comment: You shouldn't hard code "4" into your code... if the list size changes, 4 will no longer be valid.

Comment: I know it, just for sample :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem comes from #sortable height as when mouse move after the last item, the stop event is fired.

You can see an example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrGAD/1/)

Comment: I want to make this scenario If the Drag Item 2 placed after the last child of sortable -> the sortable list reject the Drag Item 2 and the Drag Item 2 back to its position. But in your example the scenario not happened.